# PHP sensitivity analysis script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP based application which calculates a final outcome based on the user inputs in several forms.

For simplicity, let's say a user starts the application, on the next page he enters a value of 5, which is sent by _post to the next page, on the next page the user enters 2 and on the final page the outcome calculates 5*2= 10 (all the values are saved to _SESSION).

My question is whether there is a good script of how to manipulate this inputs on the FINAL page...let's say in a way of sliders, that the user would be able to change the earlier given value of 5 to 10, and the script will recalculate the outcome to result in 10*2=20.

My final goal is to provide the users with a sort of a sensitivity analysis tools, so that they can change their already given inputs after seeing the outcome, and see how this change would change the given outcome.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why not just do this in javascript ? why send data to php ?

Comment: The question may be too general or hypothetical. You need to give us specifics. What are you making? What is the environment (desktop, device, javascript, etc.)? And so on. Also, "sensitivity analysis tools"? Sensitivity of what? Analysis of what? What kind of tools? If the question has to do with an interactive form, or interface, for instance, then show us what you have done so far.

Comment: i am trying to make a decision-making tool..which depends on many user inputs, like objectives' ranking, utility values and so on, based on which the final decision (the best alternative is calculated)..so i want to provide a tool, using which the users can change their inputs (like objective rankings) to see if this should change their decision... [here](http://smart-decisions.net/sites/all/themes/dmtheme/app/application.php) is what i have accomplished so far

Comment: static variable will help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asume you want to have a kind of interactive thingy, when the user moves the slider, then the result should change. You should use JavaScript for the calculation, and for the Sliders probably jQuery UI.

Comment: [decision-making tool](http://smart-decisions.net/sites/all/themes/dmtheme/app/application.php) here is the link to the application im talking about.                                        you understood me right, i want something that would be quite interactive, but is there no other way to do it without javascript? for example using php/ajax solution?

Comment: Well, Ajax means Asynchronous JavaScript and XML. It is a group of related Web technologies containing stuff like HTML, CSS, DOM, XML, XMLHttpRequest and JavaScript as their connector. So I do not think you can do that without JavaScript.